# Is the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 / \langle(2,2)\rangle$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Is the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 /\langle(2,2)\rangle$ cyclic?

How do I find if quotient group is cyclic?

I see that $\langle (2,2)\rangle= \{(0,0), (2,2), (0,4), (2,0), (0,2), (2,4)\}$ and the order of quotient group is $4$.

What's the next step I need to take?

Comment: Is the divisor $(2,2)$ or $(2,3)$?

Comment: Sorry! I edited it. It's (2,2)

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518572/calculate-the-factor-group-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-6-langle0-2-rang) for an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A presentation for $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_6$ is

$$\langle a,b\mid a^4, b^6, ab=ba\rangle.\tag{1}$$

Here $a\mapsto ([1]_4,[0]_6)$ and $b\mapsto ([0]_4,[1]_6)$, so $([2]_4, [2]_6)$ corresponds to $a^2b^2$. The quotient by $\langle ([2]_4, [2]_6)\rangle$ amounts, then, to killing $a^2b^2$ in $(1)$, like so:

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_6/\langle ([2]_4, [2]_6)\rangle &\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2b^2, a^4, b^6, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^{-2}, a^4, b^6, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^{-2}, b^4, b^6, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2,
\end{align}$$

which is not cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth saying that one can solve all problems of this sort algorithmically: no thought is required.

Think of the group additively.

Write down the matrix of relations: in this case
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0\\
0 & 6\\
2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Using Gaussian reduction (with no divisions) reduce this to Smith Normal Form: in this case

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0\\
0 & 6\\
2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2\\
4 & 0\\
0 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2\\
0 & -4\\
0 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2\\
0 & -4\\
0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2\\
0 & 2\\
0 & -4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2\\
0 & 2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence the group is
$$
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2 
$$
which is not cyclic.